# which quantity is greater in bars?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

why the quantity A is greater ? because  $\bar{0.71}$ means 0.710710710?

Comment: Hi, please use [tag:algebra-precalculus] for this kind of questions. You keep using [tag:linear-algebra] but that tag is for vector spaces and linear transformations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
A=0.\overline{717}=&0.717717717\dots \\
B=0.\overline{71}=&0.717171\dots
\end{align}
Now which is bigger, $0.7177\dots$ or $0.7171\dots$?

Comment: I think the point is better illustrated by lining up the digits. I edited your answer to reflect this. I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S=0.\overline{71}=0.7171\cdots$

So, $100S=71.7171\cdots$

On subtraction, $100S-S=71$

Similarly if $T=0.\overline{717}, 1000T-T=717$

Now, $$\frac{717}{999}-\frac{71}{99}=\frac{717(100-1)-71(1000-1)}{99\cdot999}$$

$$=\frac{71700-71000-(717-71)}{99\cdot999}=\frac{700-717+71}{99\cdot999}>0$$

Comment: can I write in this way, $0.\overline{717}= 0.717717717717$ but  $0.\overline{71}= 0.7171717171?$ so the option A correct?

Comment: @mathphy, find the other answer